# C++ Creating a dynamic library using source, static archives and other dynamic libraries

Tags: c++

In my use case, I have [YAML-CPP](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp), [SQLite3](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html), and my 'data.cpp' file that I want to all be combined into the same dynamic library, 'libdata.so'.
[image: diagram of expected behavior]

I first compiled `yaml-cpp` (as an archive):

```
mkdir -p "build"
cd "build"
cmake ..
make -j5
```

to get 'libyaml-cpp.a'.

I then compile `sqlite3`:

```
gcc -c -o libsqlite3.a sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl
```

to get 'libsqlite3.a'. I know that this a C-based file, and there are differences between it and C++, but I've read that it shouldn't make too much difference here. I also know that I'm using `-lpthread -ldl` which is for dynamic loading, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

**My question is**: Can I compile my 'data.cpp' file with YAMP-CPP and SQLite3 such that they all exist in the same 'libdata.so' output file (where the linker will use the YAML-CPP and SQLite3 functions contained in 'libdata.so' when they're called by 'data.cpp')?

I have tried:

```
g++ -c -fPIC -o libdata.so \
  -Wl,--whole-archive libsqlite3.a \
  -Wl,--whole-archive libyaml-cpp.a \
  -ldl -lpthread \
  data.cpp
```

(for the sake of the snippet, all files reside in the same directory)

**UPDATE**
I added the suggestion from botje to the line and it helped in part. After more research, I found a few more pieces that progressed further:

```
gcc -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION -c -fPIC -lpthread -o libsqlite3.a sqlite3.c

mkdir -p "build"
cd "build"
env CFLAGS='-fPIC' CXXFLAGS='-fPIC' cmake ..
make -j$(CORES)
cd ..
cp "build/libyaml-cpp.a" ./

g++ -shared -fPIC -o libdata.so \
  -L./ \
  -Wl,-Bdynamic data.cpp \
  -Wl,-Bstatic -lsqlite3 -lyaml-cpp \
  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread

g++ -L./ -ldata -o tester tester.cpp
```

The library now compiles, however, when I try to link against it with 'tester.cpp', I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: libdata.so: undefined reference to YAML::detail...
```

I'm guessing this may be a flag ordering issue, but I'm not sure what order it should be then. Placing the flags for SQLite3 and YAML-CPP before the data.cpp argument fails to compile the shared library.

Comment: When linking you need to **add** `-shared` and **remove** `-c`.

Comment: @Botje I've added your suggestion to the script; it now compiles. I'm now stuck trying to understand how to properly link the libraries such that the 'data.cpp' will use the libraries in the same file, 'libdata.so'.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by bundling those libraries into `libdata.so`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Partly for deployment, partly for learning purposes. While I could use YAML-CPP and SQLite3 as dynamically linked libraries, it would be convenient to have them built into one package (especially since I'm trying to abstract those libraries behind some custom functions in 'data.cpp'). Otherwise, I am trying to better understand more complex compilation situations.

Comment: A good start is https://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html

Comment: That was a highly informative read! Definitely helps connect a lot of the loose research I've had on these sorts of problems. That being said, I found the issue; sadly not as interesting as I had hoped :). I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, here's the method that worked for me (with extra verbosity):

```sh
# Compile SQLite3:
# - Disable the plugin loader (removes the libdl dependency)
# - Compile only (-c)
# - Use Position Independent Code (-fPIC)
# - Add the PThread library
# - After compilation, archive object (for completeness)
gcc -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION -c -fPIC -pthread -o sqlite3.o sqlite3.c


# Compile YAML-CPP
# - Create (and enter) a build directory
# - Run CMAKE with -fPIC enabled
# - Run MAKE
# - Exit and copy archive from build directory
mkdir -p "build"
cd "build"
env CFLAGS='-fPIC' CXXFLAGS='-fPIC' cmake ..
make -j$(CORES)
cd ..
cp build/libyaml-cpp.a libyaml-cpp.a


# Compile Shared Library
# - Ensure shared (-shared) (also prevents looking for a 'main')
# - Use Position Independent Code (-fPIC)
# - Use current directory for locating libraries
# - Set target CPP file
# - STATICALLY link from SQLite3 and YAML-CPP archives
# - DYNAMICALLY link from PThread library (used by SQLite3 for thread-safe access)
g++ -shared -fPIC -o libdata.so data.cpp \
  -L./ \
  -Wl,-Bstatic -l:sqlite3.o -lyaml-cpp \
  -Wl,-Bdynamic -pthread


# Compile Test Program
# - Specify current directory for includes and libraries
# - Link dynamically to 'libdata.so' 
g++ -I./ -L./ -ldata -o tester tester.cpp
```

The last issue I encountered ended up being a missing include directory for YAML-CPP.

A couple of notes for credit:

- @Botje: For pointing out that I need *-shared* and not *-c* in the compilation of a shared library. (libdata.so)
- @Maxim Egorushkin: For linking to a [very useful document](https://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html) on the matter.

One thing to note as well, is that when linking against a C library in a C++ program, you may need to use 'extern "C"' (as elaborated in the linked page). This is especially important when using the SQLite3 library.

Comment: You are getting there, I am very pleased you read that link. `-lpthread` is a historical obsolete nonsense (to choose between a non-POSIX compliant and a compliant implementation of Pthreads API; the non-compliant implementation no longer exists). Use `-pthread` when both compiling and linking.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-pthread-1

Answer (score 0):

Note that linking `.a` files into `.so` is rather unusual. People do that, but for wrong reasons.

When you link a `.so`, provide individual `.o` files compiled with `-fPIC`. Don't pack those `.o` files into `.a` first, that doesn't make much sense.

---

Why? Because `.a` file is merely a bunch of `.o` files. There is no point in making a `.a` file from a bunch of `.o` files just to turn that then into `.so` file.

To make a static library one builds `.o` files and *packs* them into `.a`. In fact, *static library* is a wrong name, technically, `.a` file is an *archive* (of `.o` files). Archives cannot link to other libraries they need because `.o` file cannot carry dependencies, neither can `.a` files.

To make a shared library one builds `.o` files with `-fPIC` option and *links* them into `.so`, along with any required libraries (static or shared). This is the `.so` file that carries dependency information on other `.so` files, `.a` archives are linked in.

When you build a `.a` that means you trade *sharing code* (in form of `.so`) for *maximum execution efficiency* (in the form of linking **parts** of `.a` into your executable directly). That means you build `.o` files without `-fPIC` option (it introduces extra access overhead) and bundle them into `.a`. Note, that `.a` file cannot refer to other libraries it needs (unlike `.so`), it is just a bunch of `.o` files. Static library `.a` is *almost* just a form to refer to multiple `.o` file. For local builds you should use *thin archives* that don't copy `.o` into `.a` rather refer to `.o`.

Also note, that when you link `.a` archive, only those `.o` files from the archive get linked into your executable (or shared library) that resolve currently unresolved symbols (unless `--whole-archive`). That means, if you have a global/namespace scope object with a constructor and link that into `.so` then it links in everything from the supplied object files and your global object constructor runs as expected. However, if you link in `.a`, the linker only pulls in those symbols/object-files that resolve currently undefined symbols, so that if your global object isn't referred to (possibly indirectly) from a file with `main` function, it won't be linked in and its constructor won't run.

---

For your purpose of building one `.so` from multiple 3rd-party libraries, you should compile those libraries' object files with `-fPIC` but not link them into `.a`. Then you link all those `.o` files into one `.so` file with all the libraries required by those comprising `.o` (either statically or dynamically).

---

With regards to `-lpthread` this is sadly a very common misconception perpetuated by POSIX standard wording being out of date.

In the old days there were two implementations of Pthreads API on Linux (and probably other systems): LinuxThreads and NPTL. POSIX standard merely says that if you want POSIX-compliant behaviour then link NPTL, not LinuxThreads and that is what that `-lpthread` linker option for. They fail to explain this reasoning or remove that sentence because it is woefully out of date.

Nowadays, modern Linux, and probably other systems, provide **only** the POSIX-compliant version. Hence, that `-lpthread` flag is obsolete, serves no purpose and isn't sufficient to build correct multi-threaded programs.

When you build multi-threaded programs you need to follow the documentation of your compiler. `gcc` and `clang` require using `-pthread` flag for both compiling and linking.

Comment: I agree, having to archive my `.o` into a `.a` is redundant. The main reason for that was that the syntax for including the library was `-lsqlite3`, which implies the existence of `libsqlite3.a`. I've updated my answer such that it instead shows `-l:sqlite3.o`; the colon syntax seems to fix that. Now, would it make any difference if I do `-l:sqlite3.o` or simply place `sqlite3.o` after the target source file (so that it is compiled with it)?